# Escondendo menu irmão

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho um menu principal que está em **li h3** e os submenus estão em **li h4**. Na estrutura, estão como irmãos. Dentro da mesma **ul** e na mesma estrutura de **li**.
Quando eu clicar no menu **li h3** quero que o menu **li h4** suma. 
Eu fiz isso com o JQuery:

```js
$('.itemSubmenuMobile ul li h3').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.itemSubmenuMobile ul li h4').toggle(300);
});
```

O item **li h4** está sumindo corretamente. Mas a **li** que fica acima de **h4** ainda permanece. No caso, some só o conteúdo e fica o espaço da **li**. Como eu faria para sumir a **li** também?

```html
<ul style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
  <li>
    <h3>
      <a href="/produtos/papeis-de-parede-1">Item 1</a>
    </h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/decorativo-8">Subitem 1</a></h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/rustico-7">Subitem 2</a></h4>
  </li>
<li>
    <h3>
      <a href="/produtos/papeis-de-parede-1">Item 1</a>
    </h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/decorativo-8">Subitem 1</a></h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/rustico-7">Subitem 2</a></h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Queres que ambos os `h4` sejam fechados?

Comment: Mudar o HTML era mais lógico. Isso é possível?

Comment: @Sergio HTML não tenho como mudar. Sim, quero que feche os **h4**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o `.closest('li').nextAll('li')` para ir buscar os próximos `li`. Depois faz um `.each` e interrompe-o se um dos descendentes do `li` for um `h3`.

```js
$('ul li h3').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('li').nextAll('li').each(function() {
    if (this.firstElementChild.matches('h3')) return false;
    $(this).toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
  <li>
    <h3>
      <a href="/produtos/papeis-de-parede-1">Item 1</a>
    </h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/decorativo-8">Subitem 1</a></h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/rustico-7">Subitem 2</a></h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>
      <a href="/produtos/papeis-de-parede-1">Item 2</a>
    </h3>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/decorativo-8">Subitem 1</a></h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="/produtos/rustico-7">Subitem 2</a></h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```